# replace values from db to a html template file in python?

Tags: python, html

I have one html template file which is in .txt format. There are certain places in the file, which I need to replace with db data. I am using the python format method. But unfortunately I can't understand how to replace with db data. I am new to python. Any help greatly appreciated.

below one is my EmailTemp.txt file (where I have to put the data)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="30%" align="center" valign="top" style="width:135px;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:10px">
<a href="">
{0} 
 </a> <!-- put image url -->
</td>
<td width="70%" align="left" valign="top" style="width:75%">
<p style="margin:0px 0 ; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#212635;font-size:16.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.4em;letter-spacing:-.2px;font-weight:bold">

 <a href=""> 
<font style="color:#1d1d22"> [Guide] {1}  </font>   <!-- put title here -->
</a>
</p>
<p style="margin:0px 0 3px  0 ; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#73787e;font-size:12.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.55em;font-weight:normal;padding-top:0px">
{2} <!-- put text here -->
</p>
    <p style="margin:20px 0px 13px 0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff402a;font-size:14px;text-align:left;line-height:1.3em">
        <a href=""> 
<font style="color:#ffffff">Checkout Guide<small>▶</small>
</font>
</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;height:30px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="30%" align="center" valign="top" style="width:25%;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:0px">
<a href=" ">
{0}
</a> <!-- put image url -->
</td>
<td width="70%" align="left" valign="top" style="width:75%">
<p style="margin:0px 0 ; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#212635;font-size:16.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.4em;letter-spacing:-.2px;font-weight:bold">

 <a href=""> 
<font style="color:#1d1d22"> [Guide] {1}  </font>   <!-- put title here -->
</a>
</p>
<p style="margin:0px 0 13px 0; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#73787e;font-size:12.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.55em;font-weight:normal;padding-top:0px">
{2} 
</p> <!-- put text here -->
    <p style="margin:20px 0 3px 0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff402a;font-size:14px;text-align:left;line-height:1.3em">
<a href=" "> <font style="color:#ffffff">Download Refcard<small>▶</small></font> 
</a>
</p>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;height:30px">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="30%" align="center" valign="top" style="width:25%;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:0px">
<a href=" ">
{0} 
</a> <!-- put image url -->
</td>
<td width="70%" align="left" valign="top" style="width:75%">
<p style="margin:0px 0 ; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#212635;font-size:16.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.4em;letter-spacing:-.2px;font-weight:bold">

 <a href=""> 
<font style="color:#1d1d22"> [Guide] {1} <!-- put title here --> </font>    
</a>
</p>
<p style="margin:0px 0 13px 0; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#73787e;font-size:12.5px;text-align:left;line-height:1.55em;font-weight:normal;padding-top:0px">
{2}  <!-- put text here -->
    <p style="margin:20px 0 3px 0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff402a;font-size:14px;text-align:left;line-height:1.3em">
<a href=" "> <font style="color:#ffffff">Download Refcard<small>▶</small></font> 
</a>
</p>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;height:30px">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Below One is my python code where I am iterating over count try to put 
 in the file.**

```
sql_query = "select * from article limit 3"
articles_details = helper.execute_given_query(sql_query);

print ("articles_details " ,articles_details)
f = open("/home/EmailTemp.txt", 'r').read()

article_text=[]
article_title=[]
image_id=[]
count =0
for j in range(0,3):
    print  "------------------------------------"
    #( articles_details[j])
    print ( articles_details[j]['title'].encode("utf-8"))
    print(article_title.append(articles_details[j]['title'].encode("utf-8")) )
    print(article_text.append(articles_details[j]['text'].encode("utf-8")) )
    #image_id= "<img src='"+articles_details[j]['url']+ "'/>"
    image_id.append(("<img src='"+articles_details[j]['url']+ "'/>").encode("utf-8"))
    count = count+1



for k in range(0,count+1):
    f.format(image_id[k],article_title[k],article_text[k])
```

Comment: Are you unable to use a third party module for this? you could use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Comment: `re` can be used, however, the input format is unclear (list of integers, strings, or lists of dictionaries?). Also, would `{2}` corresponding to the third element in an input list, or a key of `2` in an input dictionary?

Comment: @Ajax1234 that ({0},{1}.{2})is for putting the values(which is coming from db).